# How to use chinese character as associate key in php7's mysqli query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, encode

For my mysql database.

```
mysql> show variables like 'character%';
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                         |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                          |
| character_set_connection | utf8                          |
| character_set_database   | gb2312                        |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                        |
| character_set_results    | utf8                          |
| character_set_server     | utf8                          |
| character_set_system     | utf8                          |
| character_sets_dir       | F:\wamp\mysql\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+

mysql> show variables like "collation%";
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | gb2312_chinese_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci   |
+----------------------+-------------------+
```

I want to select some info with mysqli in php7.
The file named `getdata1.php` was encoded in `utf-8`.

```
My getdata1.php file.
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "xxxxxx", "student");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM student";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    print_r($row);
    $result->close();
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

I got the following output.

```
Array ( [ID] => 1 [学号] => 11410104 [姓名] => 陈XX)
```

As i know that Chinese character can be used both in associate key and value for php's associative array.
Now i want to get data with `$row["姓名"]`.
With the following file `getdata2.php` encoded in `utf-8` too,i got nothing.

```
My getdata2.php file.
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "xxxxxx", "student");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM student";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        printf ("%s \n", $row["姓名"]);
    }
    $result->close();
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

To check log file in apache.

```
Notice:  Undefined index: \xe5\xa7\x93\xe5\x90\x8d in F:\\wamp\\apache2\\htdocs\\getdata2.php on line 7
[Sun Aug 12 20:25:23.217182 2018] [:error] [pid 12204:tid 1264] [client 127.0.0.1:54023]
```

The `\xe5\xa7\x93\xe5\x90\x8d` string is `姓名`'s utf-8 encode.

```
python3
>>> b"\xe5\xa7\x93\xe5\x90\x8d".decode("utf-8")
'姓名'
```

How to use chinese character as  associate key in php7's  mysqli query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch_row()` generates an indexed array.

You are offering chinese characters when numbers are expected, change your function to `fetch_assoc()`.

To empower you to make this realization in the future, you should write `var_export($result->fetch_row());` when you are stuck, so that you can see what is *actually* in the 1-dim array and determine why your element accessing attempt is unsuccessful.

And as a matter of good general practice, you should replace `*` in your query with the lone column that you intend to use -- this way the resultset doesn't contain any needless bloat.

Comment: Apart from the resultset not containing any needless bloat, using `*` may also result in huge performance penalties.

Comment: My table contain very small dataset,only ten lines.